# Get on Map returns null

Tags: apex

I have the following code. Although it seems i give the same map, the "get" on line 36 returns me null.
You can run on anonymous console the `testOrchestratorClass.startOrderOrchestrationProcess();`
command. Could you please assist me on what i am doing wrong?

```
public class testOrchestratorClass {
    
    public class mtd
    {
        public string Product_Service_Type {get;set;}
        public string Record_Type {get;set;}
        public string Change_Type {get;set;}
        public string level {get;set;}
    }
    
    public static Map<mtd, String> mapOrchestratorProcessTemplates() {
        Map<mtd, String> orchestrationProcessTemplateMap = new Map<mtd, String>(); //initiate a new map    
        for(Integer i=0; i<1; i++){
            mtd tmpMetadata = new mtd();
            tmpMetadata.Product_Service_Type = null;
            tmpMetadata.Record_Type = 'Individual';
            tmpMetadata.Change_Type = null;
            tmpMetadata.level = 'csord__Order__c';
            String currentProcessTemplate = 'New Residential Electricity Order';
            orchestrationProcessTemplateMap.put(tmpMetadata, currentProcessTemplate);
        }
        system.debug(orchestrationProcessTemplateMap);
        return orchestrationProcessTemplateMap;
    }
    
    public static void startOrderOrchestrationProcess(){
        try{
            Map<mtd, String> orchestrationProcessTemplateMap = mapOrchestratorProcessTemplates(); 
            system.debug(orchestrationProcessTemplateMap);
            mtd mtdOrder = new mtd();
            mtdOrder.Change_Type = null;//order.csordtelcoa__Opportunity__r.csordtelcoa__Change_Type__c;
            mtdOrder.Product_Service_Type=null;
            mtdOrder.Record_Type = 'Individual';
            mtdOrder.level = 'csord__Order__c';
            system.debug(mtdOrder);
            system.debug(orchestrationProcessTemplateMap.get(mtdOrder));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            system.debug('error');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `tmpMetadata` used in `mapOrchestratorProcessTemplates` method and `mtdOrder` used in `startOrderOrchestrationProcess` method are not the same, even though both are of type `mtd`. So, in line # 36, you are trying to get an entry in the map that doesn't exist yet. What did you actually want to achieve in this code?

Comment: I want to achieve avoiding iteration in my code for every item of the map. So, because i have lots of attributes, i created the sub-class and stored them there. I have to take the information from a "matrix" custom metadata types and i was a bit confused on how i can optimize this code.

Answer (score 1):

The key in map is hashed. So your key changes when you try to do use a `new` keyword while fetching the value from `orchestrationProcessTemplateMap`

If you need to fetch the value fetch it by iterating the `key` from map like shown below.

But again, what are you trying to achive by keeping key as a class and value as string.

```
public static void startOrderOrchestrationProcess(){
    try{
        Map<mtd, String> orchestrationProcessTemplateMap = mapOrchestratorProcessTemplates();
        system.debug(orchestrationProcessTemplateMap);
        //mtd mtdOrder = new mtd();
        //mtdOrder.Product_Service_Type = null;
        //mtdOrder.Record_Type = 'Individual';
        //mtdOrder.Change_Type = null;
        //mtdOrder.level = 'csord__Order__c';
        //system.debug(mtdOrder);
        // system.debug(orchestrationProcessTemplateMap.get(mtdOrder));
        for(mtd eachKey : orchestrationProcessTemplateMap.keySet()){
            system.debug(orchestrationProcessTemplateMap.get(eachKey));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        system.debug('error');
    }
}
```